# AHK script goes idle when monitor is off

Tags: autohotkey

My title didn't say too much, but I'll try and explain:

I have a Windows 10 machine running a Minecraft server, I access the server through Remote Desktop, when I'm connected to te server via remote desktop, and run my script, I can see it working, if I close the connection to the remote desktop, it only outputs the first line.

This is my first ever attempt to make an AHK scrit, so it might be far from optimized, but this is my script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
WinActivate, mc-server
IfWinActive, mc-server
Loop 
        {
        Sleep, 60000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 3 hours{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 3600000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 2 hours{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 3600000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 1 hour{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 3000000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 10 minutes{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 540000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 1 minute{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 50000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 10 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 9 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 8 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 7 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 6 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 5 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 4 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 3 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 2 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting in 1 seconds{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 1000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, say restarting...{Enter}, mc-server
        Sleep, 2000
        ControlSend, ahk_parent, stop{Enter}, mc-server
        }
```

What can be done to fix this?
*EDIT* Sorry if I did not explain tis too good, please let me know if any info is missing.
*EDIT2* I fixed it, my hour to milliseconds where way of, I must have been tired, so it works 100% now. I'm still totally new too this.

Comment: So is only the AHK script affected? Does the server keep working?

Comment: Yes, the server keeps running ust fine, only the AHK somehow gets idle although, when I reopen te remote connection, AHK sit just fine in the tray and is green and running.

Comment: Just a thought, would it hel, if I made a new user on the server fr running the Minecraft server and script?